# Apple M2 to use performance cores when plugged in

Tags: macos, ventura

I have noticed that whenever plugged in my M2 Air macbook will still use efficiency cores predominantly, which are clocked lower.

I'd like it to actually use performance cores first if i'm plugged in which is usually when im doing work.

It is plugged in with 100W (older 2019 16" macs power adapter), so it definitely has more than enough power to draw from.

It also definittely has no issues with heat. Temperatures are nearly always at 60C (i have done some minor modifications with thermal pads to this mac air and i never saw it overheat in my daily use).

Also in battery section i have Low Power Mode = Never.

In short i'm sure its not lack of power and its not the temperature, it seems to be programmed to do this.

Is there any way to influence this?

Comment: What tasks are you doing, and are you sure that you would see a real-world benefit?

Comment: yes mostly i do software development, however i have performance tests which i run ocasionally... those tests have code in them that spins cpus at 100%, busy loops...

What is interesting is that when i run them instead of slowdown i notice bump in responsiveness of the machine. For example i'll run them and switch to chrome or something else, and it feels like i just switched a 24hz monitor for 120hz... its hard to describe but the machine is more responsive and its noticeable.

Comment: So what bothers me is that only under stress it would unlock all that performance (dont get me wrong M2 cpus are insane already, and its just unbelivable that i can get so much raw power in a machine that has no active cooling), but the fact that it is capable to be more performant but never shows it under normal use imo is incorrect. 

I do not think apple did it deliberately, they are optimising for battery life, but some of us are constantly plugged in to power/external monitor, we do not carea bout battery life.

Comment: What i would do is : under normal use you should get the most performance, only unplugged and battery under say 40% you would have the default behaviour that we have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand from your comments that it is in particular Intellij IDEA that you want to use the performance cores, and not only the efficiency cores.

You can suggest to the system that you want a running programming to use performance cores by running a command in the Terminal like this:

```
taskpolicy -B -p <PID>
```

where  is the process ID of that program. You can look that up in Activity Monitor or using the `ps` command.

Note that this is not a guarantee that performance cores will be used, as there are cases where that is not possible. I.e. if you have more threads runnable that are eligible for performance cores than you have physical cores, the overall throughput of the system would be higher by running some of them on efficiency cores rather than not running them at all.

You can inspect what the current requested and effective QoS policies are for a running program, by running this command in the terminal:

```
sudo taskinfo <PID>
```

again substitute  with the process ID of the process, you want to examine.

You'll see there in particular whether or not the process is currently scheduled with "background priority" (which typically means it will run on efficiency cores) - and you can see the QoS clamp (think of this as the maximum quality of service, you have requested to be provided to this running program).

In addition to the "background priority" that we can manipulate with the `taskpolicy` command above, we can also set other QoS policies. Such as for example setting a new requested throughput tier:

```
taskpolicy -t 5 -p <PID>
```

this will request a process to be set up for throughput tier 5 (tiers 0-5 are available, 3 is the default).

Similarly you can use:

```
taskpolicy -l 5 -p <PID>
```

to set the latency tier (tiers 0-5 are available, 3 is the default).

For an easier "systemwide" overview, you might consider running the `powermetrics` program. Use the `--show-process-qos-tiers` parameter to show QoS tiers - for example a command line like this:

```
sudo powermetrics --show-process-qos --show-process-qos-tiers --show-cpu-qos --samplers tasks -n 10 | less
```

Comment: thanks, yes this is basically the only way to achieve what i want, it does work
however imo this should be part of the OS just like you can say that "hey i do not want to use touchbar with intellij (just show f keys)" you should be able to dedicate applications to be above any performance limitations... 

For most people they know an app or two that they would never want bottlenecked, not for battery not for anything else.

I did explain this to apple support, and they seemt ot get it, hopefully we will have a feature like that down the road.

Comment: I doubt such a feature will come as it (in my experience) will have a very limited audience. You might think that an OS definitely should work like that, but I don't think most users of Macs will agree that they have one app or two that should definitely in all cases just be allowed to run before anything else - and that they care enough about this to want to set it up in the Settings panel. But it would be good if Apple released some sort of "Power Tools" for advanced users that allowed you to do just that.

Comment: thats the sad reality of apple products/software, they only do things for masses, and that is why some people worship linux. 

I've opened an issue for intellij to support a setting to start it with highest QoS... since only application can dictate this.

Comment: They can add that feature, definitely - but you can actually start it with the highest QoS class yourself… it’s not something the application dictates.

Comment: And by the way, I haven't actually seen this implemented in the GUI on any of the major Linux distributions either. There you have to manually fiddle with CPU affinity - very similar to macOS, but with its own set of drawbacks.

Comment: yes i do not mean that linux has specifically this, but it has millions of config flags so if you want some strange thing likelye it is out there and you can get it with some flag change... which is almost never the case with mac... both have pros and cons but thats a forever debate.

Comment: I think part of that is that most are simply not aware of the many, many options, configurations, flags, etc available in some form on macOS (and that’s coming from a Linux user and developer)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think users have a great deal of influence over what cores are used when. Priorities can be set by app writers, but Apple have done an awful lot of work to streamline the dispatching process around the key goals of energy efficiency, and ensuring that threads get just the right amount of power they need.

A lot of workload is still classed as low priority, which means it gets relegated to efficiency cores, and of course high priority workload may still be affected by other factors, such as being IO-bound.

Howard Oakley has done an extremely thorough job of analysing how this all works, and shows how efficiency cores probably do more work that you realise.

https://eclecticlight.co/2022/10/03/making-the-most-of-apple-silicon-power-1-m-series-chips-are-different/

There is some information on policies and how the user can have some control over QoS, which may be what you are looking for. But you cannot promote workloads from efficiency to performance QoS (of which there are multiple tiers), only demote them (and re-promote if applicable). Their QoS is set by the application code when a task is created, whether it be pThread, Dispatch queue, async / await.

https://eclecticlight.co/2022/10/20/making-the-most-of-apple-silicon-power-5-user-control/

See also this earlier discussion [How does macOS decide when to use M1's performance vs. efficiency cores?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426874/how-does-macos-decide-when-to-use-m1s-performance-vs-efficiency-cores?rq=1)

Comment: Thats very useful, but thats roughtly exactly what i expected the cores to do.
It makes sense that most of the work is done by efficiency cores.
However as a user, you should be able to say "i want Intellij IDEA to run on P cores only" 

do you know any way to do that?

Comment: As the linked articles (and further articles by the same author) state, you cannot promote workloads from efficiency to performance QoS (of which there are multiple tiers), only demote them (and re-promote if applicable). Their QoS is set by the application code when a task is created, whether it be pThread, Dispatch queue, async / await... Answer updated.